# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, newtons-method

Lot of similar questions but still not able to make it. Here is my
[code in vb.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z23gD.png) and this is the json response. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIynR.png) I know this is because of [] but i'm using list don't know still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to post the real classes of the object your want to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are receiving a JSON array and not a single JSON object.

You need to deserialize the array like this -

```
Dim Items_Array = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T())(jsonString)
```